# Batch change song names in Google Play Music

Tags: google-play-music

I have a substantial amount of user-uploaded songs on Google Play. A good portion of these have ".mp3" at the end of the file name.

Is there any way that I can batch remove this ending from all of the songs I have in Google Play? Native is obviously better if possible, but selecting multiple tracks won't let me edit the track name.

I looked into [this unofficial API](https://github.com/simon-weber/gmusicapi) but it [doesn't seem to support this functionality](https://github.com/simon-weber/gmusicapi/issues/301). I also tried searching for ".mp3" in Play's search bar but this didn't even work to find tracks with this ending.

Comment: Related: [Find song and artist names with special characters in Google Play](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/125825/140514)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this in JavaScript because all of the song data is in an `IndexedDB` that's stored on the client side. Here's the code:

```
(function () {
    console.log("Starting to update values...");
    indexedDB.databases().then(info => {
        const name = info.find(db => db.name.indexOf("music_") === 0).name;
        indexedDB.open(name).onsuccess = e => {
            const t = e.target.result.transaction("tracks", "readwrite"); 
            t.oncomplete = () => {
                console.log("Updating values completed.")
            }
            t.objectStore("tracks").openCursor().onsuccess = e => {
                if (e = e.target.result) { 
                    let data = JSON.parse(e.value);

                    Object.values(data).forEach(t => {
                        t[1] = t[1].replace(".mp3", ""); // Song name 
                        t[6] = t[6].replace("mp3", "");  // Something Play creates based on song name
                    });
                    e.update(JSON.stringify(data));
                    e.continue();
                }
            }
        }
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
})()
```

Interestingly, this seems to only affect tracks on the "songs" section of Google Play - at least initially. When I go to a specific playlist the changes I made don't seem to be transferred over. I'll continue investigating...